# Why cannot Save a File with PySpark in my system? SaveAsTextFile Doesn't Work

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from commons.Utils import Utils

def splitComma(line: str):
    splits = Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)
    return "{}, {}".format(splits[1], splits[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("airports").setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    airports = sc.textFile("in/airports.text")
    airportsInUSA = airports.filter(lambda line : Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)[3] == "\"United States\"")

    airportsNameAndCityNames = airportsInUSA.map(splitComma)
    airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_in_usa.text"
```

This is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Data Engineering Projects\8. Apache Spark\python-spark-tutorial> spark-submit .\rdd\airports\AirportsInUsaSolution.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Data Engineering Projects\8. Apache Spark\python-spark-tutorial\rdd\airports\AirportsInUsaSolution.py", line 18, in <module>
    airportsNameAndCityNames.saveAsTextFile("out/airports_in_usa.text")
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1828, in saveAsTextFile
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1309, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/C:/Users/User/Documents/Data Engineering Projects/8. Apache Spark/python-spark-tutorial/out/airports_in_usa.text already exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:131)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.assertConf(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1090)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1088)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1061)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:964)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:962)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1578)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1578)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1564)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1564)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:551)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile$(JavaRDDLike.scala:550)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have already setted HADOOP_HOME and the others system environments.
It looks like the spark cannot write in my system.

I have this Java installed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXCgA.png)

I'm trying to run some tutorial examples that are supposed to work.

What can I do?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: In the exception you can see `FileAlreadyExistsException` and the path `C:/Users/User/Documents/Data Engineering Projects/8. Apache Spark/python-spark-tutorial/out/airports_in_usa.text`. You nee to rename the file or delete the existing one.

Comment: The text says "airports_in_usa.text already exists" - what's unclear about that?

Comment: Are you missing a parenthesis at the end of saveAsTextFile?

Comment: I've already tried deleting those files and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The parenthesis is in the code, sorry It was a posting error.

Answer (score 0):

You have run your application twice, and the output directory `out` has already file named `airports_in_usa.text`

As `airportsNameAndCityNames` is an RDD, there's no opportunity you can overwrite mode. Unlike DataFrames API you have to save mode to control if your location contains data you can overwrite/append.

However, you can prior check if the files are there and delete them.

##### Remove a file from local file system

```
import os
os.remove('/home/somedir/out')
```

If you're using HDFS, you can remove files from code or before submit your application you need to

```
hdfs dfs -rm -R -skipTrash /some/somedir/out
```

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work either. Thank you for the answer. I've deleted everything in the 'out' folder, and even the 'out' folder, and It remains the same error. I think it's something about permissions maybe?